# there is a shadow in my toolbar and I don't understand how to remove it

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I don't understand why above on the screen, where the toolbar is, it is covered with a black shadow, when I go down it disappears and when I go up it reappears, I don't know how to do it, this is the code please help I've been looking for the problem for a week

```
MDBottomNavigationItem:
        name: "screen-4"
        icon: "cog"
        AKSilverAppbar:
            #elevation: 0
            max_height: '250dp'
            title:'Setting'
            left_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda x: None]]
            right_action_items: [["magnify", lambda x: None]]
            pin_top: True
            hide_toolbar: True
            radius: dp(20)
            toolbar_bg: app.theme_cls.primary_color #rgba(234,123,235,0)
            AKSilverAppbarHeader:
                elevation: 0
                MDScreen:                        
                    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
                    MDBoxLayout:
                        
                        adaptive_height:True
                        orientation: "vertical"
                        pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
                        spacing:"20dp"
                        MDBoxLayout:
                            size_hint:None,None
                            size:'85dp','85dp'
                            pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
                            Image:
                                source: "assets/images/profile-pic.png"
                                allow_stretch: True
                                keep_ratio: False
                        MDLabel:
                            text:'example@email.com'
                            halign:"center"
                            adaptive_height:True
            AKSilverAppbarContent:
                padding:'20dp'
                spacing:'20dp'
                id: content
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: "vertical"
                MDLabel:
                    text:"COMMUNICATIONS"
                    adaptive_height:True
                MDCard:
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height:"180dp"
                    orientation:"vertical"
                    radius:20
                    padding:"10dp"
                    TwoLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Wireless and Network"
                        secondary_text: "Wi-Fi . BlueTooth"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "assets/images/wifi.png"
                    TwoLineIconListItem:
                        text: "SMS"
                        secondary_text: "sms manager . Airplane mode"
                        divider:None
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "assets/images/sim-card.png"
                MDLabel:
                    text:"NOTIFICATIONS"
                    adaptive_height:True
                MDCard:
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height:"80dp"
                    orientation:"vertical"
                    radius:20
                    padding:"10dp"
                    TwoLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Notifications"
                        secondary_text: "Status bar . Do not disturb"
                        divider:None
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "assets/images/bell.png"
                MDLabel:
                    text:"DEVICE"
                    adaptive_height:True
                MDCard:
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height:"450dp"
                    orientation:"vertical"
                    radius:20
                    padding:"10dp"
                    TwoLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Lock Screen"
                        secondary_text: "Screen lock type"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "assets/images/password.png"
                    TwoLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Sounds and Vibration"
                        secondary_text: "Sound mode . Ringtone"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "assets/images/volume.png"
                    TwoLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Calls"
                        secondary_text: "Calls . Contacts"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "assets/images/phone-call.png"

                    TwoLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Storage"
                        secondary_text: "Storage . Memory"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "assets/images/sd-card.png"
                    TwoLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Battery"
                        secondary_text: "Device Protection"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "assets/images/smartphone.png"

                    TwoLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Apps"
                        secondary_text: "Default apps . App setting"
                        divider:None
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "assets/images/mobile-app.png"
                MDLabel:
                    text:"PERSONAL"
                    adaptive_height:True
                MDCard:
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height:"310dp"
                    orientation:"vertical"
                    radius:20
                    padding:"10dp"
                    TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                        text: "Dark Theme"
                        secondary_text: "switch between dark and light themes"

                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "assets/images/dark-mode.png"
                        IconRightWidget:
                            icon: "checkbox-marked" if app.theme_cls.theme_style == "Dark" else "checkbox-blank-outline"
                            on_release:app.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light" if app.theme_cls.theme_style == "Dark" else 'Dark'
                            theme_text_color:'Custom'
                            text_color:app.theme_cls.primary_color

                    TwoLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Location"
                        secondary_text: "Locations permissions . Locations requests"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "assets/images/placeholder.png"
                    TwoLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Languages"
                        secondary_text: "Input Languages . Keyboard Languages"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "assets/images/global.png"

                    TwoLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Date and Time"
                        secondary_text: "Time zone"
                        divider:None
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "assets/images/schedule.png"
                MDLabel:
                    text:"ACCOUNTS"
                    adaptive_height:True
                MDCard:
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height:"240dp"
                    orientation:"vertical"
                    radius:20
                    padding:"10dp"
                    TwoLineIconListItem:
                        text: "FaceBook"
                        secondary_text: "Facebook accounts settings"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "assets/images/facebook.png"
                    TwoLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Google"
                        secondary_text: "Google accounts settings"
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "assets/images/google.png"
                    TwoLineIconListItem:
                        text: "Whatsapp"
                        secondary_text: "Whatsapp accounts settings"
                        divider:None
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "assets/images/whatsapp.png"


                MDLabel:
                    text:"ABOUT"
                    adaptive_height:True
                MDCard:
                    size_hint_y:None
                    height:"80dp"
                    orientation:"vertical"
                    radius:20
                    padding:"10dp"
                    TwoLineIconListItem:
                        text: "About Device"
                        secondary_text: "Phone name . Status . Legal information"
                        divider:None
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: "assets/images/info.png"
```

python code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel, MDIcon
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton, MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import FakeCircularElevationBehavior
from kivymd.uix.responsivelayout import MDResponsiveLayout
from kivymd.uix.scrollview import MDScrollView
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import IRightBodyTouch
import kivymd_extensions.akivymd

class Container(IRightBodyTouch, MDBoxLayout):
    adaptive_width = True


Window.size = (340, 630)

class FirstWindow(MDScreen):
    pass

class SecondiWindow(MDScreen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Tab(FloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    pass

class ProfileCard(MDFloatLayout, FakeCircularElevationBehavior):
    pass

class MyApp(MDApp): 
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "LightBlue"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = 'A700'
        self.help_str = Builder.load_file('MyApp.kv')
        return

    
    def python1():
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1pge.png)